# store data locally in phonegap-app

Tags: mysql, html, phonegap-build

I am my new phonegap-app. This is not my first app. I am using build.phonegap.com

I have come across a situation where the user should be able to:

1. Store data locally, that will be temporary.
2. Update the complete data (i.e. sync with mysql database) when the user wants.

Till now i have built the apps using the phonegap.com website, where the user only uploads the `myapp.zip` file and the phonegap makes the `myapp-debug.apk` file for you.

But i do not understand how do i store the data locally, the database will be exact replica of the myqsl database. Need your assistance. Thank you..

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: This is not my first app. I am **not using** the desktop app. I am getting the build from phonegap.com where i upload my app in zip file(as i mentioned in second last point above).

Comment: You have five (5) methods to [store data](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/storage/storage.html), localStorage, indexedDB, webSQL, and file, plus plugins that support different methods. How are you storing data on your server? MySqL? Sql? other? **AGAIN** *Put the response in the post!* Then respond in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It appears as if your question is too broad and/or opinion-based and is likely to be closed as a result. I suggest that you re-word your question to ask a specific coding question rather than a broad request for ideas.

Comment: Also, phpMyAdmin is not a database, it's a tool for administrators to manage several different database systems; you should use the tag for your database instead.

Comment: my mistake.., i actually meant the mysql database.